# Inexplicable behavior of a for-loop after a reduce in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, recursion, reduce

**Problem:**

- For-loop inside of a function is returning an inexplicable result (1st picture, highlighted in yellow on line 150)
- Same for-loop copy-pasted outside of the function returns the expected result (2nd pic, highlighted in purple on line 164)
- I am not looking for feedback on the approach to the algo problem - only trying to understand the above

**Context:**

- rock-paper-scissors algo problem, to return an array of nested arrays representing the permutations of hands possible, based on number of rounds played passed in as argument
- function is recursive, with 'n' rounds to play as argument, [[]] as default parameter
- lines 136 - 142 : because total permutations possible is 3 ^ n, it takes the default parameter and duplicates each element 3 times (newOutput)
- lines 146 - 149 : for-loop through newOutput, adding 'rock' to first, 'paper' to second, 'scissors' to third nested array, so on

---

**Question**

The duplication of elements in line 136 is impacting the result of for-loop at 146, but why? It's inexplicable since the thread of execution has already moved onto line 146.

---

[1st picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20De.png)

[2nd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfUL6.png)

code below:

```js
function rockPaperScissors(num, output = [[]]) {

  // when num is 0, return output
  if (num === 0) return output;
  const moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

  // take output parameter, and duplicate each of the existing nested array 3 times 
  const newOutput = output.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let i = 1;
    while (i <= 3) {
      acc.push(curr);
      i++
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])

  // iterate through newOutput, push to each nested array rock first, then paper, then scissors, so on 
  for (let i = 0; i < newOutput.length; i++) {
    newOutput[i].push(moves[i%3]);
  }

  return rockPaperScissors(num - 1, newOutput);
}

rockPaperScissors(1)
// should return [[rock], [paper], [scissors]]
// instead, returns [[rock, paper, scissors], [rock, paper, scissors], [rock, paper, scissors]]
```

Comment: The code in your images has `newOutput[i].push(…)`, the code you posted as text doesn't.

Comment: You're never using the `moves` array, how are the moves supposed to get into the result?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're pushing the SAME element (Object) output[0] *n* times into the accumulator, creating *n* clones of it, which later becomes the `newOutput`.
Since those represent the SAME instance, every operation executed on one of them, will have a side effect on the others.

---

#### How to solve it?

You could solve it, by using a spread operator, which copies the value of an array into a new one.

```js
...
      acc.push([...curr]);
...
```

---

Some good reading: https://javascript.info/object-copy

Comment: this is super helpful - really good to know that elements within an array acts same as passed by reference like the object it is. thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this:

```
  while (i <= 3) {
    acc.push(curr);   // these are not copies, it's all the same array
    i++
  }
```

This is not creating copies of the `curr` array, it just pushes the same reference 3 times. All of those 3 elements refer (or point to) the same underlying array. What you have is something like this:

```
  [  ref_0,   ref_1,   ref_3  ]

      |         |        |
      |         |        |
       `---------`--------`--------------> []
```

When you try to modify the contents of the pointed-to array through one of those references, all of the other "see" the change, because it's all the same array:

```
  [  ref_0,   ref_1,   ref_3  ]

      |         |        |
      |         |        |
       `---------`--------`--------------> ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
```

The runnable snippet below demonstrates this.

Note that you can replace each reference with something else just fine; the problem only becomes apparent when you modify the *contents* of the array they point to. In other words, you can do this:

```
  newOutput[0] = "something else"

  [  ref_0,   ref_1,   ref_3  ]

      |         |        |
      |         |        |
      |          `--------`--------------> ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
      | 
       `---------> "something else"
```

If you want copies, you have to make them explicitly, by using the spread operator. Assuming the inner object in `output` is always an array, you can copy it like this:

```
acc.push([...curr])
```

If you don't have a compelling reason to use reduce, you can do this instead:

```
// [...Array(3).keys()]  produces the range [0, 1, 2]
// Use that with .map to create your copies.

const newOutput = [...Array(3).keys()].map(i => [...output[0]]);
```

```js
const output = [['Array Content']];

const newOutput = output.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let i = 1;
  while (i <= 3) {
    acc.push(curr);   // these are not copies, it's all the same array
    i++
  }
  return acc;
}, []);


displayInDiv('output-div-1', newOutput);
// shows: [["Array Content"],["Array Content"],["Array Content"]]


// Since all elements refer to the same underlying array, 
// modifying its contents through one of them affects all of them
output[0][0] = 'Modified Content';

displayInDiv('output-div-2', newOutput);
// shows: [["Modified Content"],["Modified Content"],["Modified Content"]]

displayInDiv('output-div-3', newOutput[0] === newOutput[1]);
displayInDiv('output-div-4', newOutput[1] === newOutput[2]);
// shows true in both cases
// it means that it's all the same object


function displayInDiv(divId, objectToShow) {
  const div = document.getElementById(divId);
  div.innerText = JSON.stringify(objectToShow);
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.description {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.output {
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">Result of reduce: </div>
<div id="output-div-1" class="output"></div>

<div class="description">After modification of array content: </div>
<div id="output-div-2" class="output"></div>

<div class="description">newOutput[0] === newOutput[1]: </div>
<div id="output-div-3" class="output"></div>

<div class="description">newOutput[1] === newOutput[2]: </div>
<div id="output-div-4" class="output"></div>
```

Comment: amazing. this was it. thank you for the prompt and detailed response